# How to retrive specific rows from a matrix returned by reading a CSV file in java

Tags: java

I want to retrieve some rows of a 2d array.

example: I have file named as "data.csv", which contains

```
age   sex  zipcode   classtype

21     m     23423   1

12     f     23133   2

23     m     32323   2

23     f     23211   1
```

The below mentioned code will give output like this:

```
{age=[21,12,23,23],sex=[m,f,m,f],zipcode=[23423,23133,32323,23211],classtype=[1,2,2,1]}
```

Now I want to retrieve rows which have classtype 1 and store this values in a new 2d array.

like `partition1={{21,m,23423,1},{23,f,23211,1}}`

```
    public class CsvParser {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "data.csv");
                Map<String, List<String>> values = parseCsv(fr, " ", true);
                System.out.println(values);
                List<List<String>> partition1 = new ArrayList<>(25);
                List<String> classTypes = values.get("classtype");
                for (int row = 0; row < classTypes.size(); row++) {
                     String classType = classTypes.get(row);
                     if ("1".equals(classType)) {
                     List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(25);
                     data.add(values.get("age").get(row));
                     data.add(values.get("sex").get(row));
                     data.add(values.get("zipcode").get(row));
                     data.add(values.get("classtype").get(row));
                     partition1.add(data);
                  }
           }

                 System.out.println(partition1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> parseCsv(Reader reader, String separator, boolean hasHeader) throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<String>> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> columnNames = new LinkedList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        int numLines = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split(separator);
                    if (tokens != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
                            if (numLines == 0) {
                                columnNames.add(hasHeader ? tokens[i] : ("row_"+i));
                            } else {
                                List<String> column = values.get(columnNames.get(i));
                                if (column == null) {
                                    column = new LinkedList<String>();
                                }
                                column.add(tokens[i]);
                                values.put(columnNames.get(i), column);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ++numLines;
                }
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your immediate problem is, `Map` makes no guarantee in which order the keys are maintained.  You would, actually, be better to use `List<List>`, where the first entry where the `headers`...Mind you, I'd be using a pre-existing CSV library if you could...

Comment: I can't get your code to meet your basic expectations....

Answer (score 1):

```
             FileReader file1 = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file1);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                       String[] str = line.split(",");
                       if(str[0]!=null||str[1]!=null||str[2]!=null){
                       sb.append("'" + str[0] + "',");
                       sb.append("'" +str[1] + "',");
                       sb.append("'" +str[2] + "'");
                       }
```

CSV File Must to be split comma based it should be work

Comment: Hows that answer the OP's question?  How does that produce the desired 2D array from the matrix based on the `classtype`?

Answer (score 0):

Once I changed `Map<String, List<String>> values = parseCsv(fr, "\\s,", true);` to `Map<String, List<String>> values = parseCsv(fr, " ", true);` I was able to get the data in the right format...

From there it was just a matter to read through each row of `classtype`, when I found a value that matched `1`, I would pull out each property for the given row and add it to a `List`, forming a single row.  This was then added to another `List` which would maintain all the matching rows, for example...

```
List<List<String>> partition1 = new ArrayList<>(25);
List<String> classTypes = values.get("classtype");
for (int row = 0; row < classTypes.size(); row++) {
    String classType = classTypes.get(row);
    if ("1".equals(classType)) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(25);
        data.add(values.get("age").get(row));
        data.add(values.get("sex").get(row));
        data.add(values.get("zipcode").get(row));
        data.add(values.get("classtype").get(row));
        partition1.add(data);
    }
}

System.out.println(partition1);
```

Which outputs...

```
[[21, m, 23423, 1], [23, f, 23211, 1]]
```

If you're looking for a more automated method, then I'm afraid you're out of luck, as `Map` makes no guarantee about the order that the keys are stored, iterated.

Of course, instead of using a `List<List>`, you could use a `List<Map>` which would maintain the keys for each value, for example...

```
List<Map<String, String>> partition1 = new ArrayList<>(25);
List<String> classTypes = values.get("classtype");
for (int row = 0; row < classTypes.size(); row++) {
    String classType = classTypes.get(row);
    if ("1".equals(classType)) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>(25);
        for (String key : values.keySet()) {
            data.put(key, values.get(key).get(row));                        
        }
        partition1.add(data);
    }
}

System.out.println(partition1);
```

Which outputs...

```
[{sex=m, classtype=1, zipcode=23423, age=21}, {sex=f, classtype=1, zipcode=23211, age=23}]
```

Comment: It gives an error like:  cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class CsvParser,

Comment: Did you `import java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: How can I get n partitions, when n classtype are there. As of now I am getting one partition according to classtpye 1.

Comment: Depends, if you want to get each one, you need to know each type.  You could use `Set`, which will allow you to iterate over the `classtype` values, adding each value to it and will ensure that there are no duplicates, with that in had, you would then need to simply iterate over the set and replace `"1"` with the value from the `Set`...

Comment: I tried the set concept, but im not getting the idea, im new in java. Please flash some more light. It will be very helpful.